# find and replace image url source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I have an image without `class` and `id`, just `src` exists. I want to empty the `src` attribute.

```
<td class="ms-vb" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
    <img alt="" src="/_layouts/images/square.gif"/>
<td>
```

to

```
<td class="ms-vb" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
    <img alt="" src=""/>
</td>
```

I need to find this image among several images in HTML. How to do that?

Comment: Just that specific image?  Andy why not remove it entirely rather than removing the src?

Comment: you need to _"find this image in several images"_.  What?

Comment: @kingjiv: well, that is another option

Comment: @kingjiv Removing it entirely will make the page invalid. `src` [is required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) but is allowed to be an empty string.

Comment: @andy I meant the entire item, not the src.  What good is an image with no src?

Comment: @kingjiv heh, yes very true, removing the `src` will just result in a broken image icon in most browsers. Sorry I misunderstood your comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('img[src="/_layouts/images/square.gif"]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("src","");
});
```

Anyway, @kingjiv is right, is better for you to remove it entirely:

```
$('img[src="/_layouts/images/square.gif"]').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: somehow both are not working. Is there any we can use <td> class.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `attr` and `remove` are only applied to the first element in the set. To apply to all, you must use `each`. Fixed my answer.

Comment: What's happening? Please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', '');
});
```

will empty all `src`. You can change the first selector to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "img[src='/_layouts/images/square.gif']" ).attr( 'src', '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the parent class :

> $('td.ms-vb img').attr('src','');